# How do I make my Django website act as an open id provider? I want logged in users to be able to use my site as an openid provider

Tags: django, openid, openid-provider

I don't want to let my users login to my site with an openid.

I want all of my users who login to my site with their username and password to be able to use my site as an openid server/provider to login to other sites.  Is there a Django plugin available to enable this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe one of these will be useful:
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/310/
http://www.romke.net/django/openid_provider/introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried it out, but I saw this come across twitter yesterday:
http://bitbucket.org/romke/django_openid_provider/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two projects worth looking at based on these two URLs:

- http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources
- http://splike.com/wiki/Django_OpenID

OpenID-auth and OpenID-consumer:

- https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth
- http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-consumer/